# What are the subjects, objects, complements and gerunds in this sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, gerunds, subjects, objects, complements

> As with most great avant artists, it’s easier to describe how Arca makes you feel than what it is, exactly, she makes.

Just wanted clarification on a few things. What is the first part of the sentence considered in terms of grammar?

> as with most great avant artists

I thought it was a subject complement at first, but I'm not sure. The subject of the first main clause already has a complement, I think, in the phrase 'easier to describe' which qualifies the verb 'be' (of the subject 'it'). Am I correct in thinking this? And am I also correct to consider 'makes you feel' as the complement of the object 'Arca', or is 'how Arca makes you feel' an entire gerund phrase, as another noun could be substituted? How do I demarcate these things here - and in future?

And in the second clause (if it is a second clause, and not just another complement full of non-finite verbs)

> than what it is, exactly, she makes

Am I correct to think 'it' is the subject, 'what' the adverb, 'is' the main verb, and 'makes' a gerund?

Sorry if that reads a bit convoluted - it's quite a few questions at once. I guess what I'm asking for is general syntactic analysis of the sentence - any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The first part is a verbless clause functioning as an adjunct of comparison. The main clause subject is the dummy pronoun "it" and the predicate VP is "is easier to describe how Arca makes you feel than what it is, exactly, she makes". “Easier to describe how Arca makes you feel” is an adjective phrase with “easier” as head and the infinitival clause “to describe how Arca makes you feel” as its complement. “How Arca makes you feel” is an NP in a fused relative clause functioning as object of “describe”. “

Comment: cont ... "Than what it is exactly, she makes” is a preposition phrase with “than” as head and “what it is exactly, she makes” an NP in a fused relative construction functioning as complement of “than”.